list all tags of docker image in GCP Artifact Registry
I want to list all image tags that i have in GCP Artifact Registry, because i have more than 100 tags and only up to 100 are shown in the UI.
I found this question, but it's about Container Registry which is deprecated:
How do I list images and tags in google container registry

You can do this with the following command:
gcloud artifacts docker tags list <location_of_your_image>
This page proved me helpful:
https://fig.io/manual/gcloud/artifacts/docker/tags/list
The official docs could also be helpful:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/tags/list
